# Is this rational function convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-definite, rational-functions, hessian-matrix

For $x_1, x_2 > 0$, let

$$f(x_1,x_2) := \frac{1}{x_1^3x_2}$$

Is function $f$ convex?

---

I think it is because Hessian matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{12}{x_1^5x_2} & \frac{3}{x_1^4x_2^2} \\ \frac{3}{x_1^4x_2^2} & \frac{2}{x_1^3x_2^3}\end{pmatrix}$$

And I think the matrix is positive because each value is positive (is it true?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A twice differentiable function is convex iff its Hessian matrix is positive-semidefinite. Your Hessian matrix is good, but instead of considering its elements, you need to consider
$$
\frac{12}{x_1^5x_2}x_1^2+\frac{3}{x_1^4x_2^2}(x_1+x_2)+\frac{2}{x_1^3x_2^3}x_2^2
$$
which also appears to be nonnegative given that $x_1,x_2>0$. And yes, it is convex.

Comment: i belive u wanted to show that a^T * H * a is always positive.. but the answer for that is (12a1^2)/(x1^5*x2) + (2*3*a1*a2)/(x1^4*x2^2) + (2a2^2)/(x1^3*x2^3) which im not sure how to show that its positive for any a1,a2 from R

Comment: @AdarCohen Oh sorry I did't read your comment carefully. Yes you are right that is the definition of positive-semidefinite. But as you said, it seemed not easy to show that $x^THx$ is positive, so I chose to use another methodology.